# Best ActiveRecord inheritance strategy for abstract class and subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

trying to figure out the best ActiveRecord inheritance strategy for this particular problem:

I have an abstract class, let's call it `Message` with the following methods/attributes.

```
Message
  |- recipient
  |- sender
   \ body
```

And I have two sub classes

```
ColorMessage < Message
  |- first_color
  |- second_color
   \ body (returns "#{sender.name} says #{first_color} > #{second_color}")

WeatherMessage < Message
  |- current_weather_adverb
   \ body (returns "#{sender.name} enjoys #{current_weather_adverb} weather")
```

I'd like to be able to run a query for all `Message`s and display their bodies without having to worry about their concrete types. Basically treating `Message` as an interface.

I am familiar with STI, is that the correct solution in this case?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider this an appropriate use for single-table-inheritance (STI(.

You can ask for Message.all or ColorMessage.all and rails will take care of the object casting for you.